# Optimize Kubuntu for 4k hidpi displays

Tags: kubuntu, kde, scaling, 4k-monitor

:)

I'm using Kubuntu and a 4K display, 3840*2160 resolution at 282dpi (my laptop is a Dell XPS 15" 9550).

I have followed [this guide](https://www.girialam.com/2016/02/kubuntu-and-hidpi-screen/) to setup everything, and it is stunning, but i have a problem. On some windows, elements are not displayed the way they should.

I've joined [some screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXOLU.jpg) of Chrome and Sublime Text. As you can see, Chrome tabs and search bar are way too big, and Sublime Text side bar and text editor (even though ctrl+scroll fixed that last one) are way too small.

You can also see that i've tried to modify Scale display options, to set it to 1, but when i reboot it doesn't change anything.

Anyway, does anyone know how to fix this ? This is really annoying..